# Using python matplotlib to create multi line graph

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, linegraph

I'm looking to create a line graph with the y axis having multiple lines for each unique entry found within my dataframe column.

My dataframe looks like this –

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'command': ['start', 'start', 'hold',
                               'release', 'hold', 'start',
                               'hold', 'hold', 'hold'],
                   'name': ['fred', 'wilma', 'barney',
                            'fred', 'barney', 'betty',
                            'pebbles', 'dino', 'wilma'],
                   'date': ['2020-05', '2020-05', '2020-05',
                            '2020-06', '2020-06', '2020-06',
                            '2020-07', '2020-07', '2020-07']})
```

I'm trying to create a line graph with the X axis as the date, and the y axis would have a separate line for each of the command entries(start, hold, & release in this example).

I tried using a groupby then executing this –

```
dfg = df.groupby(['command', 'date']).size()

for i in dfg.command.unique():
    x = dfg[dfg.command==i]['date']
    y = dfg[dfg.command==i]['size']
    plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

However I get this error - AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'command'

I've also tried creating a pivot table and building the graph from there as follows -

```
df_pv = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['command', 'date'],
                       values='name',
                       aggfunc='count')
df_pv.rename(columns={'name': 'count'}, inplace=True)

for i in df_pv.command.unique():
    x = df_pv[df_pv.command==i]['date']
    y = df_pv[df_pv.command==i]['count']
    plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

However it returns the error - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'command'

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in my approach?

Or if there is a better method of achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. As the first error indicated `df.groupby(['command', 'date']).size()` returns a Series with a multiindex. If you want to work with that, you can turn it into a dataframe using `.reset_index()`

```
dfg = df.groupby(['command', 'date']).size().reset_index()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for com in dfg['command'].unique():
    ax.plot(dfg.loc[dfg['command']==com,'date'],dfg.loc[dfg['command']==com,0],'o-', label=com)
ax.legend()
```

Note that you could also directly work with the MultiIndex (although I generally find it more cumbersome).
You can iterate over a specific level of the multiindex using `groupby(level=)` and access the content of a given level using `MultiIndex.get_level_values()`:

```
dfg = df.groupby(['command', 'date']).size()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for com,subdf in dfg.groupby(level=0):
    ax.plot(subdf.index.get_level_values(level=1),subdf.values,'o-', label=com)
ax.legend()
```

Finally, if you want to save you the trouble of writing the loop yourself, you could use `seaborn`, which is pretty easy to use for this kind of plots (although you will need to transform your dataframe like in the first solution)

```
dfg = df.groupby(['command', 'date']).size().reset_index()
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(data=dfg, x='date', y=0, hue='command', marker='o')
```

If you want to be really fancy, you can dispense of transforming your original dataframe yourself, and let `seaborn.lineplot()` do it, by instructing it how to aggreage the values for each date:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='date', y=0, hue='command', estimator=pd.value_counts, marker='o')
```

all of these solutions yield the same output, with some minor esthetic differences.

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation to go along with the answer. Helps tremendously.